# String Matching for /* and */

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file including the lines below:

```
/* MY TXT File LINE */
/* MY TXT File LINE MORE */

constant private FileName = <A "C:\\TMP\\ALARM.TXT">

constant ConfigAlarms = <U1 0>    /*  Comment Here*/
```

I don't know how to divide the comment lines (`/* something */`):

LINE1:

```
/* MY TXT File */
```

LINE2: (acturally i don't think the line is a really comment line.)

```
constant ConfigAlarms = <U1 0>    /*  Comment Here*/
```

my code below.

```
if ($val =~ /\/\*/){
    print "<!-- $line -->";
    print "\n";
}
```

LINE1 and LINE2 will be treated as comment.

I googled and found the information below.

```
^f     # f at the beginning of a line
^ftp   # ftp at the beginning of a line
e$     # e at the end of a line
tle$   # tle at the end of a line
```

but i don't know how to combine `/*` with the `^` and `$` character to improve my code to parse the Line starting with `/*` and end with `*/`

Thank you.

Comment: I have to ask why you are trying to parse out `/*` and `*/`? If you are parsing some script using a new language, you should create a specialized parser for that language. If it's a configuration file, use one of the well-established formats such as YAML or JSON.

Comment: I plan to convert a big size txt file to XML file.
There are some /* */ comment lines in the txt file. i must parse it out and add the XML comment "<!-- $line -->" style. It is more easier to read the new XML file leter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m{^/\*.*\*/$}
```

will match lines that have `/*` as their first two characters and `*/` as their last two.

Comment: @Nano, it's important to note that Anon's suggestion uses {} instead of // in the regular expression. It makes the regular expression easier to read.

Comment: Also note that, like most regex solutions, this will fail if you happen to have a string in your source code that contains `"/* comments */"`. If this is a problem, a parser is in order.

Comment: /*MY TXT File */   -- There is no blank space between * and M, it works well now.
/* MY TXT File */   -- There is one or more than one blank spaces between * and M, it doesn't work.
How to handle it? thanks.

Comment: Unless something else in your script is mangling the input, this should work fine regardless.

Comment: This non-greedy multi line version will allow for multi line comments `m{ ^ /\* .*? \*/ $ }xms`  Save you some *//*'s. :)

Comment: @Anon,
Acturally, my TXT file is very large size. i must handle both the comment style above. 
And there file was created automatically, all my team members take use it. That's why i must think about the two conditions.

Comment: I don't think you actually understood what I wrote. So I'll say it straight this time: *the regex I posted will handle both styles*. Either there are problems elsewhere in your script, or the text file has characters before the opening / or after the closing one.

Comment: Awesome. Good luck with whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

See this [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file%3f). Instead of ignoring text matching the given pattern, capture it.

Alternatively, you can give [String::Comments::Extract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Comments::Extract) a shot. See [`String::Comments::Extract::C->collect( <source> )`]([http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/String::Comments::Extract#String::Comments::Extract::C-%3Ecollect(*%3Csource%3E*)](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/String::Comments::Extract#String::Comments::Extract::C-%3Ecollect(_%3Csource%3E_)).

Answer (score 2):

There is an incredible CPAN module that can help with this, [Regexp::Common::comment](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm).  Using it is incredibly easy:

```
use Regexp::Common qw /comment/;

while (<>) {
    /$RE{comment}{C}/       and  print "Contains a C comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{C++}/     and  print "Contains a C++ comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{PHP}/     and  print "Contains a PHP comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{Java}/    and  print "Contains a Java comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{Perl}/    and  print "Contains a Perl comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{awk}/     and  print "Contains an awk comment\n";
    /$RE{comment}{HTML}/    and  print "Contains an HTML comment\n";
}

use Regexp::Common qw /comment RE_comment_HTML/;

while (<>) {
    $_ =~ RE_comment_HTML() and  print "Contains an HTML comment\n";
}
```

You should be able to easily extend this to cover multi-line comments.